# Is PYTHONPATH consistent across multiple import statements even if some of them manipulate the sys.path?

Tags: python, pythonpath

The PYTHONPATH documentation https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH says that "The search path can be manipulated from within a Python program as the variable sys.path."

I.E. another module is free to edit the sys.path and append anywhere to the list or even make it empty.

My understanding is that in order to preserve consistent search order PYTHONPATH is used, is it not ?

Let's assume "y" module changes sys.path in a script A.py
import x
import y
import z

1. Python interpreter sees PYTHONPATH and the sys.path gets updated by the interpreter it then imports x
2. import y appends a new path to either start or end of the sys.path list, it means that it will import the sys module as well.
3. Now, since the sys.path has been changed in y, based on how the import statements work https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.modules my understanding is that the sys.path is changed permanently until the interpreter shutsdown. Maybe reloading the sys module again in A.py would reset the sys.path to use PYTHONPATH search order ?

I am looking to have a consistent search order path in the top level module which I believe can be affected by another sub module/imports changing it. Is PYTHONPATH the way to get this or is there some other tip/trick that I am not aware of yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your module y changes `sys.path`, the value will be the same on your A.py script even if you execute `importlib.reload(sys)`

So imagine module 'y' executes

```py
from sys import path
path.clear()
```

In your A.py script:

```py
import sys, importlib
import x, y

importlib.reload(sys)
print(sys.path) # is []

import z
```

The module z will not be found.

To fix this you can restore your script `sys.path` variable to the same value assigned at the beginning by the interpreter. 
From the documentation:

> A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules. Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default.

And...

> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter

Lets assume that the interpreter is not running in interactive mode or read from stdin (Its executing a file script) and its located on the current working directory 
Our A.py could look like:

```py
import importlib

import x, y

# We can still load (sys, os, ...)
from sys import path
from os import getcwd
import site

print(sys.path) # []

path.append(getcwd()) # Add directory where script is executed
path.append(os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH')) # Add PYTHONPATH
site.main() # Add site packages

import z # Now this dont fail
```

Note: Even removing all `sys.path` items, `importlib` is able to locate the packages `os`, `site`, `sys`, ...

This is because `importlib` uses `sys.modules` to access such packages:

From [importlib.find_loader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.find_loader) documentation:

> If the module is in sys.modules, then sys.modules[name].**loader** is returned

And from the [sys.modules](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.modules) documentation:

> This is a dictionary that maps module names to modules which have already been loaded.

---

EDIT: 
This is a tricky solution that you can use to solve this problem: You can create a function which is invoked everytime you load a module. The function checks if `sys.path` is changed after the module is loaded.
If true, set it to its original value

```py
from copy import copy
import warnings
import sys

sys.path = list(sys.path)
_original_path = copy(sys.path)
_base_import = __import__

def _import(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        module = _base_import(*args, **kwargs)
        return module
    finally:
        if type(sys.path) != list or sys.path != _original_path:
            warnings.warn('System path was modified', Warning)
            # Restore path
            sys.path = copy(_original_path)

__builtins__.__import__ = _import
```

And now execute this code:

```py
import sys

before = copy(sys.path)
import y # 'y' tries to change sys.path
after = copy(sys.path)

print(before == after) # True
```

It will also display a warning message on stdout

---

EDIT #2 (Another solution): 
This works only on python >=3.7 because it relies on [PEP 562](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/) 
Here I basically replace the module 'sys' so that i can avoid external modules to change the actual `sys.path`

First create a script with the next code (proxy.py):

```py
import importlib
from sys import path, modules
from copy import copy

path = copy(path)
modules = copy(modules)

def __getattr__(name):
    if name in globals():
        return getattr(globals(), name)
    return getattr(importlib.import_module('sys'), name)

def __dir__():
    return dir(importlib.import_module('sys'))
```

Now, on your A.py, put the next code:

```py
import proxy
import sys
sys.modules['sys'] = proxy

import y # y imports 'sys' but import sys returns the 'proxy' module
# 'y' thinks he changes sys.path but it only modifies  proxy.path

print(proxy.path) # []
print(sys.path) # Unchanged
```

Code on y module:

```
import sys
sys.path.clear() # a.k: proxy.path.clear()

# You can still access to all properties from the sys module
print(dir(sys)) # ['ps1', 'ps2', 'platform', ...]
```

Comment: so python interpreter uses sys.path to populate system independent paths, while site provides an interface to add system/user dependent paths ?
Some package is flipping the first two paths in my debian, which I want to find out and one way to avoid this by explicitly setting the order in PYTHONPATH and restoring it as you have shown above
<code>
print('\n'.join(site.getsitepackages()))
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
/usr/lib/dist-python
</code>

Comment: You just do site.main()

Comment: It adds user and system dependent packages.

Comment: got it, if there's another package say 'p' which comes after 'z' and changes path so we will have to reset the path again ? I am wondering if there is some way for us to keep the path consistent/constant in 'A.py' independent of how other imports might change it

Comment: Edited my response. Added a possible solution.

Comment: The PEP 562 solution is great, unfortunately I am stuck with 3.4 for now. I will go with the tricky solution, thank you for enlightening me with more python !